# Call a function using a discriminated type based on a key that lives outside of the type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a function which allows users to pass in a key and depending on that key the function will accept a specific payload. I'm having trouble though because for some reason the function does not understand the discriminated union.

Here's a recreation:

```
type SharedOptions = {
  pageSize: number;
  pageIndex: number;
};

type Projects = {
  input: {
    tasks: string[];
  };
};

type Workspaces = {
  input: {
    members: string[];
  };
};

const functionMap = {
  projects: (input: Projects["input"]) => {},
  workspaces: (input: Workspaces["input"]) => {},
};

const SharedOptionsFunctions = [
  "projects",
  "workspaces",
] as const satisfies readonly (keyof typeof functionMap)[];
type SharedOptionsFunctionName = typeof SharedOptionsFunctions[number];

function execute<T extends SharedOptionsFunctionName>(
  name: SharedOptionsFunctionName,
  input: Parameters<typeof functionMap[T]>[0]
) {
  const fn = functionMap[name];
  return fn(input);
}
```

The issue happens on the last line: `fn(input)`. The error is:

```
Argument of type '{ tasks: string[]; } | { members: string[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ tasks: string[]; } & { members: string[]; }'.
  Type '{ tasks: string[]; }' is not assignable to type '{ tasks: string[]; } & { members: string[]; }'.
    Property 'members' is missing in type '{ tasks: string[]; }' but required in type '{ members: string[]; }'.(2345)
input.tsx(15, 5): 'members' is declared here.
```

How do I let the TypeScript compiler know that depending on the name the user passes in, the parameter may differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the indirect specification via `functionMap` is too deep for TypeScript. You can either create a mapping interface which defines common types for the `execute` function and the `functionMap` object:

```js
interface Mapping {
  workspaces: Workspaces['input'];
  projects: Projects['input'];
} 

type FunctionMapping = {[K in keyof Mapping]: (input: Mapping[K]) => void}

const functionMap: FunctionMapping = {
  projects: (input) => {},
  workspaces: (input) => {},
};

function execute<T extends keyof Mapping>(
  name: T,
  input: Mapping[T],
) {
  const fn = functionMap[name];
  return fn(input);
}
```

or, you could also add a type assertion to input like this:

```js
function execute<T extends keyof typeof functionMap>(
  name: T,
  input: Parameters<typeof functionMap[T]>[0]
) {
  const fn = functionMap[name];
  return fn(input as any);
}
```

`any` casting is normally bad practice, in this case you could argue that you know better, as the code will run fine and TypeScript is just not smart enough. I'd prefer the first solution because it does not require type assertions.